# I cannot click buttons in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, controller

this is a snapshot from the program:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w64ZS.jpg)

In this scene, I cannot click text fields, checkbox and button which are in a GridPane but i can traverse them with TAB button. Another interesting fact is that, when I pressed TAB, it goes in this order: name-surname-email-confirm email-password-details-confirm password-selectcity-phone

I couldn't understand why I cannot click and why order is not normal. Note: I can click other texts such as Home Page (it's not in the gridpane)

Note: My problem is not releated to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178814/javafx-button-isnt-clickable) since i dont have a statement such as setMouseTransparent(true). Also, i am asking why TAB does not properly.

This is controller of this scene:

```
public class SignUpController
{

@FXML
private TextField nameField;
@FXML
private TextField surnameField;
@FXML
private TextField emailField;
@FXML
private TextField confirmEmailField;
@FXML
private TextField phoneField;
@FXML
private PasswordField passwordField;
@FXML
private PasswordField confirmPasswordField;
@FXML
private TextArea detailsField;
@FXML
private CheckBox signUpCheckBox;
@FXML
private Text warningMessage;
@FXML
private ComboBox cityList;

DatabaseConnector dc1 = new DatabaseConnector();

/**
 * Events when sign up button is clicked
 */

public void cityListClicked()
{
    cityList = new ComboBox();
    cityList.getItems().addAll("Emre", "yeter ulan");
}
public void signUpClicked()
{
    if(emailField.getText().equals(confirmEmailField.getText()))
    {
        if(passwordField.getText().equals(confirmPasswordField.getText()))
        {
            signUpCheckBox.setIndeterminate(false);
            if(signUpCheckBox.isPressed())
            {
                dc1.addUser(new User(nameField.getText(), surnameField.getText(), passwordField.getText(), emailField.getText(), detailsField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(phoneField.getText()), new ArrayList<RealEstate>(), new ArrayList<>()));
                warningMessage.setText("Signup successful");
            }
            else
                warningMessage.setText("You have to accept to continue");
        }
        else
            warningMessage.setText("Passwords don't match");
    }
    else
        warningMessage.setText("Emails don't match");
}  
}
```

And FXML document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.SignUpController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="86.0" layoutY="93.0" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="60.0">
         <children>
            <GridPane prefHeight="341.0" prefWidth="740.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="284.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="132.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="608.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="608.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="80.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Surname" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Email" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Confirm Email" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Password" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Confirm Password" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="City" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Phone" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                  <TextField fx:id="nameField" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="surnameField" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="13.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="emailField" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="43.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="confirmEmailField" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="73.0" mouseTransparent="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </PasswordField>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Details" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
                  <TextArea fx:id="detailsField" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="354.0" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </TextArea>
                  <TextField fx:id="phoneField" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="133.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <PasswordField fx:id="confirmPasswordField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </PasswordField>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cityList" onAction="#cityListClicked" onContextMenuRequested="#cityListClicked" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select City" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Sign up">
               <font>
                  <Font size="29.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <CheckBox fx:id="signUpCheckBox" mnemonicParsing="false" text="By signing up, I  accept the Real Estate Wizard's Terms of Service and Privacy Policy">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#signUpClicked" text="Sign Up">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Text fx:id="warningMessage" fill="#e11616" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <fx:include source="Template.fxml" />
   </children>

</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Button isn't clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178814/javafx-button-isnt-clickable)

Comment: @Bo Halim But, i dont have setMouseTransparent(true) statament in gridpane

Comment: What's inside `Template.fxml`???

Comment: The header and footer part

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is a very strange situation?

Comment: @EmreAkyıldız Header **AND** footer? I'm pretty sure they are inside a layout that gets the mouse events instead of the `VBox` behind it...

Comment: Template is AnchorPane and it has two Hboxes, one of them contains header texts the other one contains footer texts. What should I change to fix it?

Comment: Oh thank you. I modified mouseTransparent of Template as true and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @EmreAkyıldız You could also move the include to the start of the `<children>` tag, since this woul simply get the tamplate behind the gridpane instead of above it... For an `AnchorPane` the layout looks the same, regardless of the order of children. BTW the focus traversal order is determined by the order of the children in the parent. Simply reorder the `GridPane`'s children to list the children in the order in which you want the focus to traverse to fix your problem there...